# Color format a row or field based on conditions in the email i send in python with to_html

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, html-email, conditional-formatting

Im trying to format the email i send of a log file. I'm using pandas to generate the output and the to_html to send the email. I'm trying to use lambda to format the row in order to color it a certain color based on the STATUS. When I run the code it actually prints background-color: yellow instead of making the block yellow.

Im using lambda with formatters provided by to_html

```
result += df1.to_html(classes='wide', formatters={'STATUS': lambda x: "background-color: yellow" if x == "REJECTED" else ''}, escape=False)
```

I'm expecting the block to be colored in yellow.

Comment: If the status is an element just add it to that element or use it as a variable.

Comment: The STATUS is a column in the dataframe. When i use the code example I posted it actually prints background-color: yellow in the email and does not color the block yellow.